# Mongoose push into subdocuments

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, lodash

I am running on MEAN.js and I've got a problem with pushing new subdocuments into an existing database entry. What I've done so far:
I've got a following database schema:

```
var GameSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: 'Title cannot be blank',
        unique: 'Title must be unique'
    },
    invitedPlayers: [{
        email: {
            type: String
        },
        resources: {
            wood: {
                type: Number,
                default: 0
            },
            stone: {
                type: Number,
                default: 0
            },
            gold: {
                type: Number,
                default: 0
            }
        }
    }]
});
mongoose.model('Game', GameSchema);
```

and I want to push new entry into invitedPlayers. Whenever admin fill out a form with users invitation and click on submit, application will cal this method:

```
// Invite new User
$scope.invite = function() {
    // Create new Game object
    var game = new AdminGamesService ({
        _id: $stateParams.gameId,
        invitedPlayers: $scope.player,
    });

    game.$update(function() {
        $location.path('admin/users');
    }, function(errorResponse) {
        $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
    });
};
```

and it runs this on the server (`_` - lodash is used):

```
// Update game
exports.update = function(req, res) {
    var game = req.game ;
    game = _.extend(game , req.body); //here should be something that merge arrays instead of replacing them?
    game.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.json(game);
        }
    });
};
```

But this whole code overwrite my sooner invited players and add only the new one :( I must change something to push entry in array invitedPlayers, but I don't know what :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that lodash _extend overwrite arrays, so I've made some changes in update function and now it works:

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {
    var game = req.game;
    var invitedPlayers = game.invitedPlayers;
    if(req.body.invitedPlayers) invitedPlayers.push(req.body.invitedPlayers);
    game = _.extend(game , req.body);
    game.invitedPlayers = invitedPlayers;

    game.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.json(game);
        }
    });
};
```